# Katakana on Google Japanese Keyboard

Tags: applications, keyboard, gboard

In the Google keyboard, I can type most of the characters I want to type, but I'm having trouble getting the keyboard to suggest the katakana ji. Is there a specific way to coax it into doing that?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering and suggestions from someone using a different keyboard, I found a workaround.

If you type the hiragana character shi, then convert the character to katakana then the keyboard doesn't seem to contextually recognize you may be trying to type ji in katakana.

However, if you type shi in hiragana, a button in the bottom left can be used to manually add a dakuten to it. If this is done, the suggestion bar seems to recognize what you're looking for and will offer the correct katakana character.

Once I got it to work the first time, it seems to be suggesting the correct character by default.